# Install chrome browser on Linux Server

Tags: node.js, linux, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I running into a problem with an selenium automation test in Jenkins that is running on a remote Linux Server. I'm thinking it is just a matter of there being no chrome browser on that remote system. So, my question is: how can I install Chrome on the remote Linux Server? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: which version of linux are you using ??

Comment: Are you able to login to the desktop of the remote Linux server where the Selenium tests are running?

Comment: I just know the system is amd64. 4.14 32-coreos.@rohitthomas

Comment: i don't think so, cause i don't have the authentication for login the remote desktop, all i can do is execute shell within Jenkins.@AndrewGray

Comment: Chances are the remote server does not have a desktop - unlike Windows, this is normal for Linux servers. You should contact the administrator of that server to install this for you. After that you will also need to change your tests to run in headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

This should let you install chrome via terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1 libappindicator1 libindicator7
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
```

Comment: I have tried the way you mentioned. But it seems that i don't have the superuser authentication, i will consult the responsible person. Anyway, Thanks for your answer. @cannerwagon